# Upgrading MAD-GANs source code to Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: time-series, tensorflow2.0, generative-adversarial-network, anomaly-detection, multivariate-time-series

I am trying to replicate the MAG-GAN architecture presented in the paper [MAD-GAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.04997.pdf) starting from their source code: https://github.com/LiDan456/MAD-GANs.git , for a Time Series Anomaly Detection project. However, the official code uses a tensorflow version 1.4.1, and I need a 2.x (2.8 specifically). I've been stuck with this task for days, I would appreciate if you could help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have experience in code upgrade from TF1 to TF2.
In fact, it is easier to write all from scratch than to upgrade.
However, if you could post specific questions to each problem you face, you might get all issues cleared in time.